# I don't understand how to use cheerio class selectors

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I want to get the children inside this element from within the website, and the elements inside the children

Code:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

(async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`...`);
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
  
  let ChatBody = $('div[class="chatbody overflow-y-auto flex-column"]').children()
  console.log(ChatBody)
  
  /*ChatBody.each( (index, element) => {
    console.log(index,element)
  })*/
})();
```

[Code and Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a1sx.png)

[Elements screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDPkE.png)

I use nodejs v12.22.10, axios and cheerio packages, javascript*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like:

```
$('.chatbody > *').get().map(el => $(el).text())
```

This will give text of all children